# linker problems with qt4 and CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm trying to do a Qt project (Qt 4.8.6) with CMake, but i have some issues with the linker and i'm a bit lost.

Here is what i get when i do a "make" on my project:

```
chasselas:build tfaux$ make VERBOSE=1
"/Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -H/Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4 -B/Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
"/Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E cmake_progress_start /Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4/build/CMakeFiles /Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/depend
cd /Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4/build && "/Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4 /Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4 /Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4/build /Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4/build /Users/tfaux/Documents/workspace/tempQt4/build/CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/build
Linking CXX executable addressbook
"/Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/addressbook.cpp.o  -o addressbook -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib  -framework QtOpenGL -framework QtGui -framework QtCore 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "AddressBook::staticMetaObject", referenced from:
      AddressBook::tr(char const*, char const*) in addressbook.cpp.o
  "vtable for AddressBook", referenced from:
      AddressBook::AddressBook(QWidget*) in addressbook.cpp.o
   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [addressbook] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/addressbook.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is the addressbook.h:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tutorials-addressbook-fr-part1-addressbook-h.html

Here is the adressebook.cpp:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tutorials-addressbook-fr-part1-addressbook-cpp.html

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6")

#Test Cmake file for Qt applications
SET(PROJECT_NAME addressbook)
PROJECT(${PROJECT_NAME})
Find_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)
SET(QT_USE_MAIN true)

#Setting the sources of the project
SET(PROJECT_SOURCES
main.cpp
addressbook.cpp
)

SET(PROJECTS_HEADERS
main.h
addressbook.h
)

#Traitement du moc Qt
QT4_WRAP_CPP(PROJECT_HEADERS_MOC ${PROJECT_HEADERS})

#inclusions
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${TULIP_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

#creation de l'executable et liaison des librairies
ADD_EXECUTABLE(addressbook ${PROJECT_SOURCES} ${PROJECT_HEADERS_MOC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(addressbook ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_NETWORK_LIBRARY})
INSTALL(TARGETS addressbook DESTINATION bin)
```

Any help is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use lower-case commands in your cmake code. It is far more readable.
2. You have a typo. You set the PROJECTS_HEADERS variable but you pass PROJECT_HEADERS to qt4_wrap_cpp. Prefer to use an editor which makes that obvious by highlighting identical strings when selected. Fixing the typo fixes your bug.
3. Use CMAKE_AUTOMOC instead of qt4_wrap_cpp. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html It is available since CMake 2.8.6.